# Why Ubuntu wiki runs on different software to other help sites?

Tags: documentation

I'm curious why [Ubuntu Team Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) uses a different web interface to [Ubuntu documentaion](http://help.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Both are using MoinMoin Wiki engine -- http://moinmo.in. Difference is only in theme.

Comment: @Vojtech I don't think the documentation uses MoinMoin

Comment: @fluteflute that's true, official documentation not, but community cotributed (https://help.ubuntu.com/community) uses MoinMoin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) has recently been changed to use a new theme that fits far better with Ubuntu's new visual identity - new logo, colours, fonts, etc - the same things you'll see on this very site infact. For more details take a look [this blog post from Mark Shuttleworth](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/308) that introuduces the new visual feel.

Having said this, the new theme is probably not perfect yet - I would say it lacks the polish the old theme had.

The [official web documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) has not yet been changed to use the updated visual identity, but I assume it eventually will.

If you wish then in your Ubuntu Wiki [User Preferences](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserPreferences) then you can change your theme ("ubuntu" is the old one, and "light" is the new one).

[image: Two themes side by side]

Comment: BTW the preferences to change the theme seems broken.

Comment: @Tshepang: if I remember correctly you need to refresh after changing the theme.

Comment: @Jan Doesn't work.